# Unable to connect to mongohq at heroku using shell

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongohq

I installed `mongohq:sandbox` at Heroku. When I want to connect to mongo, it occurs an error:

```
mongo linus.mongohq.com:10123/app10575123 -u my_user -p pwd123
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: linus.mongohq.com:10123/app10575123
> show dbs
Wed Jan  9 06:00:50 uncaught exception: listDatabases failed:{ "errmsg" : "need to login", "ok" : 0 }
```

Login and password are correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are connected to the database, but for the shared database plans at MongoHQ (especially the sandbox ones), for security reasons, they do not include admin-level access to the Mongo instance ... only access to your actual database.

"show dbs" is an admin-level command and, in this case, would show other databases on that sandbox MongoDB process.

Instead, you will want to use commands like:

- show collections
- db.[collection_name].findOne()
- db.stats()
- db.[collection_name].stats()
- db.[collection_name].ensureIndex({foo:1, bar:1}, {background:true})

... and so on.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to `show collections`, but `show dbs` requires admin privileges.