# Unable to connect to MongoDB using password hash

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongohq

My question is similar to this one insofar as **I am trying to make a mongo *shell connection* to database that Heroku auto-provisioned on MongoHQ** (Now called Compose): [Unable to connect to mongohq at heroku using shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225576/unable-to-connect-to-mongohq-at-heroku-using-shell?rq=1)

The only details that I have about this database are from the Heroku Environment Variable:

```
MONGOHQ_URL

mongodb://heroku:yQso1cKxxxxob0RVaUy_mLN_sO0hPloxxxxxxAmEs-g@flame.mongohq.com:27066/app5xxx6
```

It would seem that the 'big long string' part is a username / password hash...

**How can I use the above connection string to make a *mongo shell connection* to the database?**

**Is there a way, through Heroku. MongoHQ to get the actual username and password?** I don't have a MongoHQ account, only a Heroku account.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a misunderstanding. There is no hashing going on.

The user name is "heroku"

And the password is - '*the big long string*'

So the solution is:

```
mongodb flame.mongohq.com:27066/app5xxx6 -u heroku -p o95y8unw74bxYWM_THE_BIG-LONG-STRING
```